# Hovering over an HTML, element underline blinks white then fades in to red

Tags: html, css

I've created an HTML web page and whenever you hover over a certain element, the underline should fade in to red. But instead, it blinks white, and *then* fades in to red. How do I fix this?

```
.nav a {
        font-size : 35px;
        color : white;
        text-decoration : none;
        position : relative;
        right : -100px;
        bottom : -20px;
        transition : 0.5s;
        opacity : 1;
    }

.nav a:hover {
        text-decoration : red underline;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because a CSS transition always needs a start value. Otherwise it can't change the property to the desired value.

So in your example, your transition goes from "nothing" to `red underline`. So the browser just adds the white underline (default underline) and then goes to red.

What you can try is to use transparent as your base color:

```css
body {
  background: green;
}
nav a {
    font-size : 35px;
    color : white;
    text-decoration : transparent underline; /* This line has changed */
    position : relative;
    right : -100px;
    bottom : -20px;
    transition : 0.5s;
    opacity : 1;
}

nav a:hover {
    text-decoration : red underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<nav>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```